# Can't copy in next empty column

Tags: vba, excel

Been struggling with this macro that's working like a charm in other sheets

```
Sub Move_Data()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Dim emptyColumn As Long

Set source = Sheets("KAMSS")
Set destination = Sheets("KA")

emptyColumn = destination.Cells(2, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If emptyColumn > 1 Then
emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
End If

Sheets("KAMSS").Range("E5:E75").Copy

Sheets("KA").Cells(2, emptyColumn).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("KA").Cells(2, emptyColumn).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats


End Sub
```

Now this macro is only overwriting whats in column 1 in `KA` for no reason I can understand. I've tried to write it all over, copied the macro from the other sheets where this works and checked if I forgot to set calculations to True.

Comment: Are you sure about the if condition ? Try If emptyColumn > 0 then

Comment: @newguy pretty sure since its working in my other workbook, and it worked at first, but it stopped moving for some reason. But tried to change it to >0 and then it counted one more, but why?

Comment: Use debug.print emptyColumn to check what the program is returning at various points in the program.

Comment: Done that and for some reason it skips the part of adding a new column with >1. But again, it's the exact same as I've used before.

Comment: It will skip that part if the condition is not met what is the value of emptyColumn before if condition ?

Comment: @newguy its a text or a value, but I tried to check a few rows down where theres only value %